# Communication to sharepoint server is canceled. (error)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am trying to host my app in office 365 but it stops on either clicking **Yes** or **No** in a prompt.

[image: Prompt Image]

When i click **No**

[image: No]

When i click **Yes**

[image: Yes]

I am new to Sharepoint Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Closed all my browser
2. Restarted Visual Studio and Changed SiteURL Offline then Online Worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is in Site URL. So, before hosting browse the Site URL and check whether its opening or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **Sever Connection** Property of App Project is set to **Offline**. Set that Property to Online,and this will ask you for credentials to connect with site, set in the **Site Url** Property.[image]